# How to change the color of "search hit BOTTOM, continuing at TOP" to red?

Tags: search, message

The message "search hit BOTTOM, continuing at TOP" was always red in my previous experience.
But in the new system, this message is in the same color as the comments in the code.
This makes the message unnoticeable.
I don't want to change the color scheme of VIM. So how to change the color of this message?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that message `:h hl-WarningMsg` highlight group is used:

[image]

[image: asciicast]

If you have colorscheme in your vimrc, then add following after it:

```
colorscheme whatever
hi WarningMsg guifg=red ctermfg=red
```

More info on how to override a colorscheme: https://github.com/vim/colorschemes/wiki/How-to-override-a-colorscheme%3F

Answer (score 0):

Found this answer online:

```
:highlight WarningMsg ctermfg=white ctermbg=red guifg=White guibg=Red gui=None
```